# Timed Image-slider with Js media-query doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to get an image-slider that should change image every two seconds to only be active if the website is smaller than 650px, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
Here is the html-code:

```
 <div class="kitchen-slider">
            <div class="kitchen-img-box">
            <img src="IMG/kitchen/kitchen.jpg " class="img" width="100%">
            </div>
            </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var slider_img = document.querySelector('.kitchen-slider');
var images = ['kitchen.jpg', 'kitchen2.jpg', 'kitchen3.jpg'];
    var x = 0;
    var max = 3;
    var m = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 650px)");


    myfunction(m);

    m.addEventListener("change",function(){
        myfunction(m);
    });
    
    function myfunction(m){
        if (m.matches) {
    function imgslider(){
       if (x < max) x=images.length;
       x--;
       return setImg();
    } 
    function setImg() {
        return slider_img.setAttribute('src','IMG/' + 'kitchen/' + images[x]);
    }
    setInterval (imgslider, 2000);
} else null;
    }
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is all bungled up .. You have nested functions and mis matched `{` `}`

Not to mention you don't need multiple functions

Also your `setInterval()` will never "keep firing" where it's at...

I changed your logic for incrementing as well -- `x === images.length` then set it to `0` -- being that the `index` starts at `0` we don't have to do any funky `>` or `<` operators.

```js
const slider_img = document.querySelector('.kitchen-slider');
const images = ['kitchen.jpg', 'kitchen2.jpg', 'kitchen3.jpg'];
let x = 0;
let m = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 650px)");

var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
  myfunction(m);
}, 2000);


function myfunction(m) {
  if (m.matches) {
    x = (x === images.length) ? 0 : x
    slider_img.setAttribute('src', 'IMG/' + 'kitchen/' + images[x]);
    console.log('src', 'IMG/' + 'kitchen/' + images[x] + " -- " + x)
    x++
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="kitchen-slider">
  <div class="kitchen-img-box">
    <img src="IMG/kitchen/kitchen.jpg " class="img" width="100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank, you for the answer. It really helps me a lot. I'm relativly new to coding so it's nice to know that people are so willing to help.

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to mark it answered :)